# かっこいくない vs かっこよくない

Tags: spoken-language

I'm confused about this because i've read both, which one is correct?

thanks

Comment: `i've read both` -- 「かっこ**い**くない？」 ・「かっこ**い**くないですか？」は俗語(slang)だと思います

Answer (score 1):

かっこ by itself means something like "appearance". The word かっこいい is an union of かっこ and いい (the adjective to say "good"), which is irregular and cojugate as よい. Because of this, the negative form of かっこいい is かっこよくない. You can also say かっこわるい.

Comment: If you saw かっこいくない and you remember where, is it a reliable source? Because I'm 99,9% sure, かっこいくない is wrong.

Comment: Obviously it wasn't reliable :p